# Min value of $F(x) = x - \sqrt{1-x^2} $

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

Min value of $F(x) = x - \sqrt{1-x^2} $

But using derivatives  $F(x) = x - \sqrt{1-x^2} $

i stucked at $2\sqrt{1-x^2} + 2x = 0$

$\sqrt{1-x^2} > 0 $

I get $-1<x<1$

Please help me?
 is there another way to solve it btw?

Comment: How'd you get that $(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})' = 2\sqrt{1-x^2} + 2x$.  I'm pretty sure that is incorrect.  Use the sum and chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f(x)$ can have its extrema at $x$ values that satisfy $f'(x)=0$.  Thus:

\begin{align}
F(x)&=x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
F'(x)&=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
0&=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
0&=\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\quad\textrm{(notice here that $x$ has to be negative)}\\
-x&=\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
x^2&=1-x^2\\
2x^2&=1\\
x^2&=\frac12\\
x&=-\frac1{\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Since the domain is $x\in[-1,1]$, we can test $F(-1)$, $F(1)$, and $F(-\frac1{\sqrt2})$.  You should be able to figure that $F(-\frac1{\sqrt2})$ will give you the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be something wrong in this (that means, your derivative): $2\sqrt{1-x^2} + 2x = 0$

My answer:

> First let's notice that the function domain is $[-1,1]$ for that $1-x^2\geqslant 0$. Then it is easy to see $f'(x)=0$ when $f(x)$ reaches to minimum. So that
>   $$
> f'(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1
> $$
>   set $f'(x)=0$ we get $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and $f(x)=-\sqrt{2}$ where it is the minimum. Rigorously speaking, you need to check the derivative on both side to judge whether it is the min value, but in this question it is obvious.

Comment: What is the maximum one?

Comment: Check derivative on both sides, which sides?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if $F(x) = x - \sqrt{1-x^2} = x - (1-x^2)^{\frac 12}$ then $F'(x) =1 - \frac 12(1-x^2)^{-\frac 12}*(-2x) = 1+\frac {x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Solving for $1+\frac {x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$ yield $x =-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ so $x^2 = 1-x^2; x \le 0$.  Or $2x^2 =1$ or $x=-\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ and

$F(-\frac {\sqrt 2}2) = -\frac {\sqrt 2}2-\sqrt{1-\frac 12}= -\frac {\sqrt 2}2 - \frac {\sqrt 2}2 = -\sqrt 2$.

Yegawds.  I made several arithmetic errors getting here!

Comment: You are wrong calculating $F'(x)$ I think.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to cancel the 2.  Working on it.

Comment: Sheesh.  My night for arithmetic errors!  $2*\frac 12= 1$ which is written as "$1$" and not "$2$".  And $2x^2 = 1$ doesn't mean $x^2 = 2$.  Sheesh!

Answer (score 1):

If the usage of calculus is not mandatory,

as $1-x^2\ge0,$  WLOG $x=\sin t,$ where $-\dfrac\pi2\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$f(x)=\sin t-\cos t=\sqrt2\sin\left(t-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

Now $-\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac\pi4\le t-\dfrac\pi4\le\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac\pi4$

$\implies-1\le\sin\left(t-\dfrac\pi4\right)\le\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Why $\sin\frac{-\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}$ become -1 ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, No, in that range $\sin$ will be minimum $=-1$ if $t=-\dfrac\pi2$