# Find the maximum value of g

Tags: limits

I am only 9th grader and i have this question for homework: find the maximum value of function g and than prove why it is the biggest: 
$$g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{x} $$
, i know that x can not be bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Have you done any calculus in class or on your own?

Comment: No and i have to solve it elementary methods

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352449/min-value-of-fx-x-sqrt1-x2/3352484#3352484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the domain is:
$$\begin{cases}1-4x^2\ge 0 \\ x\ne 0\end{cases} \Rightarrow x\in [-\frac12,0)\cup (0,\frac12]$$
Now rearrange the function by multiplying by [conjugate](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/conjugate.html):
$$g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{x}\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}=\frac{4x}{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$
Can you finish?

Hint: To increase the value of fraction, one should increase its numerator and decrease its denominator.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but can you explain what the adjugate is and how to use that?

Comment: I updated and showed what needs to be multiplied. Sorry, it is conjugate, see the link.

Comment: I am only a 9th grader...

Comment: Yes, yes, please ask and I will try to clarify

Comment: Conjugate of $1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ is $1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}$. When we multiply the two, we use the formula $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$. That is: $(1-\sqrt{1-4x^2})(1+\sqrt{1-4x^2})=1^2-(1-4x^2)=4x^2$.

Comment: You should increase the numerator, so what is the maximum you can increase $4x$? Remember $x$ can increase up to $\frac12$. Similarly, you should decrease the denominator... So, at the end you should get $g(\frac12)=2$ to be maximum value.

Comment: it is 2 and my intuition told me when i started but i just could not prove it.

Comment: Thank you for helping

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $2x=\sin2t,-\pi/2\le2t\le\pi/2,\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos2t$

$f(x)=2\dfrac{1-\cos2t}{\sin2t}=2\tan t$ if $\sin t\ne0$

Clearly $-\tan\dfrac\pi4\le\tan t\le\tan\dfrac\pi4$ as $\tan$ is always an increasing function

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't learned trigonometry